# Why does xcode 8 give error when I try to automatically manage signing?

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode8, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to test an ionic app on an iPhone but I don't have a developer account.

I tried following all the steps here: http://blog.ionic.io/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/

However, when I try to have xcode 'Automatically manage signing', I get the errors shown in the screenshot below. I also get the error: "Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching..."

What am I doing wrong? How do I make a provisioning profile? How can it say 'No profiles were found'? Isn't it supposed to make the profiles for me automatically?

[image: Errors]

Comment: *I don't have a developer account.* vs. *..is only available to users enrolled in ...* (means with developer account) ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. From everything I've read, what I am trying to do should be possible without a developer account.

Comment: Then you might disable `In-App Purchase`

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. The main thing I couldn't figure out is the second error in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the solution to this issue. I disabled in-app purchases and then the other error went away as well. To disable in-app purchases, after clicking on the name of the app in xcode, select 'Capabilities' in the center section of the screen and then find In-App purchases to turn off.